# What is the difference between commercials and ads (advertisement) and advertising?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

Is my understanding correct?

1. Advertisement is more formal than ad.
2. Advertising is a mass noun and advertisement is a count noun referring each piece of advertising.
3. Commercials can only used in pl form to mean a special type of advertisement, the video format on TV.

Comment: Merriam-Webster online gives examples of the singular use of *commercial* to invalidate your point 3.  Keep reading.

Comment: But other than the possibility of commercial singular, yes correct